# Why is subclassing TraversableOnce not recommended

Tags: scala, inheritance, collections

Reading http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce:

> Directly subclassing TraversableOnce is not recommended - instead, consider declaring an Iterator with a next and hasNext method, creating an Iterator with one of the methods on the Iterator object, or declaring a subclass of Traversable.

Why is subclassing `TraversableOnce` not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you would have to implement 12 relatively complex abstract methods, whereas with the recommended alternatives, you get that functionality much more easily.  `TraversableOnce` is there to provide a convenient abstract type for a function argument.